# Need to optimize a call to a rest service in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I need to call a rest service for each row of a dataset within spark. I produced the following code:

```
import requests

df= spark.read.parquet("file.parquet")

for row in df.rdd.collect():
  requests.post('rest.api/endpoint')
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do that, performance-wise. Is there a better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running it on `.collect` results you lose any parallization and all of the requests will be done from the driver.

You can create a UDF that will call an API for each of the rows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import requests

api = "https://swapi.co/api/people/"

@udf("string")
def swapiGetPersonName(id):
    response = requests.get(api + str(id))
    return response.json()["name"]

df = spark.range(1,10)
df.select("id", swapiGetPersonName("id").alias("name")).show()
```

However, if you have lots of data this can easily overload both your rest service or your executor. (you will pretty much do a denial of service attack on your service or run out of sockets).
If this is a concern you can either

- batch data by loading a subset of it at time
- batch it by splitting it with `foreachPartition` and processing rows one-by-one in each
- stream data using structured streaming and limit the amount of rows you process at time
- use API (or modify yours) which supports batch operations (instead of each row, upload a whole partition / significant portion of your data)

Those are from the top of my head, but besides doing too many calls to the service don't forget to add  proper exception handling :)